# Does every equivalence class in a Brauer-Wall group have a (graded) division algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, brauer-groups, central-simple-algebras, super-algebra

It is known that each equivalence class in a Brauer group has a division algebra (or, in other words, every central simple algebra is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Mat}(D)$ for some division algebra $D$). Is this true for Brauer-Wall groups? That is: each central simple $Z_2$-graded algebra is $\mathrm{Mat}_{p,q}(D)$ for some graded division algebra $D$ ?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{Mat}_{p,q}(D)$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this seems to follow from Lam's book "Introduction on Quadratic Forms over Fields", Ch. 4

Comment: I asked a clarification regarding your question above.

Comment: $Mat_{p,q}$ is the $Z_2$-graded algebra of graded transformations acting on a $Z_2$-graded space of dimension $(p,q)$.

Often it is indicated as $M_{p,q}$